# uib-pagination NOT working Angularjs

Tags: jquery, angularjs, pagination, angular-ui-bootstrap

### EDIT!

added more code snippets and plunker updated (AGAIN)

Still pretty new to Angular and coding in general.

I've tried and tried to instantiate the UI Pagination from the [Angular Directives](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/pagination) website. I've scoured Stack Overflow and codeProject and various other sites. I can not for the life of me get my pagination to work.

I don't know what else to try. I'm pretty sure I've called enough properties

```
<uib-pagination
    items-per-page="itemsPerPage"
    ng-model="currentPage"
    max-size="maxSize"
    class="pagination-sm"
    next-text="&raquo;"
    previous-text="&laquo;"
    boundary-links="false" >
</uib-pagination>
```

and running the controller:

```
app.controller('PaginationControl',function ($scope,  $window) {
    // Pagination variables
    $scope.totalItems = 100; //this needs to be changed to represent the total of filtered parks after a search is done and NOT a static number.
    $scope.currentPage = 1;
    $scope.maxSize = 8;
    $scope.itemsPerPage = 10;
```

});

What I don't understand is how to change the pagination properties from static numbers hard coded in the controller to dynamic numbers based off the results of my search.

Here's a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/hJS2HqZXyeCYKN4WxwSt?p=preview) which has everything but the pagination working.

Much obliged

Comment: The Plunker is missing jQuery and angular-animate.

Comment: I swear they were in there before. I updated. Still not seeing results. [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/WoGsJZrCWRUBVKHMhGf2?p=preview)

Comment: I only took a quick look now, might try to help later when I have time. I noticed that `display` is defined in `ListController`, but used in the DOM under `PaginationControl`. `PaginationControl` is sibling and not a child to `ListController`, so the `display`  that is passed to `uib-pagination` will be undefined.

Comment: Edited [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/WoGsJZrCWRUBVKHMhGf2?p=preview).  Still not sure.

Comment: Just to clarify @tasseKATT, why do I need jquery in my code when everything is Angular?

Comment: It's because you have included `bootstrap.min.js` which requires jQuery.

Comment: I ended up switching over to [dirPagination](https://github.com/michaelbromley/angularUtils) due to the inability to find an answer or to get my code to be more dynamic.

Comment: can you please check my question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43546340/uib-pagination-not-showing-correct-pagination-numbers ?

Comment: you should use `<div uib-pagination` instead of `<uib-pagination` see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44803009/769137

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were a couple of problems with your plunk.  You referenced the bootstrap.js files instead of the bootstrap.css file.  You referenced the angular core library for version 1.4.5 and the angular animate library for version 1.4.7.  You reference jQueryUI but not jQuery.  You did not set the total-items attribute on the pagination directive.  Here is an updated [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/hJS2HqZXyeCYKN4WxwSt?p=preview) with the pagination displaying.  Updated reference block:

```
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.7/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-filter/0.5.8/angular-filter.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.14.3/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yea. My newness to coding is shining through about now. Thank you for all the corrections @RobJacobs

Comment: can you please check my question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43546340/uib-pagination-not-showing-correct-pagination-numbers ?